# How to handle unexisting variables passed to a proc

Tags: stored-procedures, tcl, args

I would like to create a procedure like this simple example:

```
proc name {args} { 
    foreach val $args {
        puts $val
    }
}
```

But I would like the procedure to handle variables that don't exist, something like the code shown below:

```
proc name {args} { 
    foreach val $args {
        if [info exists $val] {
            puts $val
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the code is not executed because as soon as I call the procedure with an unexisting variable it immediately stalls, prior to go into the code, saying that there is a variable that doesn't exist. Is it probable because the procedure checks argument existance before entering the body?.

I can make it work by changing `args` by several optional variables with predefined values, but that limits the procedure and makes it look bad.

Can I make a proc able to handle unexisting variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a variable as an argument: arguments have to be values. You *can* pass a variable *name* as an argument and use that as a reference to the variable inside the procedure. Example:

```
proc name args {
    foreach varname $args {
        upvar 1 $varname var
        if {[info exists var]} {
            puts $var
        }
    }
}
```

(The call to `upvar` creates a link between the variable whose name is the value of the variable `varname` outside the procedure and the variable called `var` inside the procedure. This is one way to "pass a variable to a procedure".)

Then you can do this:

```
% set foo 1 ; set baz 3
% name foo bar baz
1
3
```

Note that if you try to invoke the procedure as

```
% name $bar
```

where `bar` is undefined, the interpreter tries (and fails) to evaluate it before calling the procedure. That might be what you are seeing.

Documentation:
[upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the point where you are *calling* the command (procedures *are* commands; they're a subclass really) you'll see something like this in your code:

```tcl
name $a $b $c
```

That's fine if all those variables exist, but if one doesn't, it *will* blow up even before `name` is called. In Tcl, `$a` means exactly “read the variable `a` and use its contents here”, unlike in some other languages where `$` means “look out language, here comes a variable name!”

Because of this, we need to change the calling convention to be one that works with this:

```tcl
name a b c
```

That's going to require the use of `upvar`. Like this:

```tcl
proc name {args} {
    foreach varName $args {
        # Map the caller's named variable to the local name “v”
        upvar 1 $varName v

        # Now we can work with v in a simple way
        if {[info exists v]} {
            puts $v
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake here

```
if [info exists $val]
```

When `info exists` is used **it should be checked against variable name, not the variable value.**

Lets come to your actual question.

You can pass the arguments to the procedure as a key-value pair, then it is pretty simple.

```
proc user_info {args} {
    #Converting the arguments into array
    if {[catch {array set aArgs $args}]} {
        puts "Please pass the arguments as key-value pair"
        return 1
    }
    #Assume, we need to ensure these 3 arguments passed for sure.
    set mandatoryArgs "-name -age -country"
    foreach mArg $mandatoryArgs {
        if {![info exists aArgs($mArg)]} {
            puts "Missing mandatory argument '$mArg'"
            return 1
        }
    }
}

user_info -name Dinesh
```